# File splitting in GCP cloud functions does not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am currently building a serverless application using GCP cloud functions.

In order to deploy cloud functions separately for each function, I have split the modules as follows.

When I write all the functions in index.ts, it works fine locally, but when I export it, I cannot run it with the following error.

```
'getUsers' needs to be of type function. Got: object
```

Is there something wrong with the export method?

Here is the command to run it locally

```
"start": "npm run build && functions-framework --source=build/src/ --target=getUsers",
```

#### index.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as getUsers from '@src/cloudFunctions/userFunctions';
import * as getUserById from '@src/cloudFunctions/userFunctions';
import * as updateUserById from '@src/cloudFunctions/userFunctions';
import * as deleteUserById from '@src/cloudFunctions/userFunctions';

export {
  getUsers,
  getUserById,
  updateUserById,
  deleteUserById,
};
```

#### userFunctions.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();
    
exports.getUsers = app.get('/users',
  ///logic goes here
);

exports.getUserById = app.get('/users/:id',
  ///logic goes here
);

exports.updateUserById = app.put('/users/:id',
  ///logic goes here
);

exports.deleteUserById = app.delete('/users/:id',
  ///logic goes here
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I split userFunctions.ts into separate files for each function, and changed index.ts as follows, and it worked.

I guess I was using the wrong export method.

```
//userFunctions
const getUsers = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/getUsers');
const getUserById = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/getUserById');
const updateUserById = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/updateUserById');
const deleteUserById = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/deleteUserById');
const getUserSellingItems = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/getUserSellingItems');
const getUserLatestSellingItems = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/getUserLatestSellingItems');
const getUserCollectedItems = require('@src/cloudFunctions/users/getUserCollectedItems');

//userFunctions
exports.getUsers = getUsers.getUsers;
exports.getUserById = getUserById.getUserById;
exports.updateUserById = updateUserById.updateUserById;
exports.deleteUserById = deleteUserById.deleteUserById;
```